# How to make canvas follow the scroll div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to do a simple thing. 3 div moving up and down on touch (for smartphone). On top of this 3 div, I'd like to have a canvas, to draw the edge of div. (In the example it is straight, but there will be some rotation and other beautiful canvas drawing...). I'd like to use canvas and not an img, to learn.

I use vh, vw to make it responsive. There is only 5 div.

I am not sure my solution to scroll up and down is a good idea. It represents when it is team 1 to play or team 2.

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Sulot/gzm6duzy/2/

```
#mycanvas{
pointer-events: none;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100vw;
height:100%;
z-index:5;
border: 3px solid;
}
```

This css choice doesn't sound as a good idea.

Thanks,

Stéphane.

Comment: Did you check what's in your fiddle link?

Comment: Your fiddle is empty

Comment: Sorry, I updated it. https://jsfiddle.net/Sulot/gzm6duzy/2/